# ValueError: Could not get version for Chrome with this command: reg query

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium with python and have downloaded the chromedriver for my windows computer from this site. After downloading the zip file, I unpacked the zip file to my downloads folder. Then I add the path to the  the Environment Variable "Path".

I want to get information from the site, but when I run code, I get this error and comletely don't understand what is it about.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
url = 'any_url'
browser.get(url)

if browser.find_element_by_id("yearlist_1").get_attribute("type") == "checkbox":
    print("Element is a checkbox")
else:
    print("Element is not a checkbox")
```

The error: 
*'reg' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/miair/Python/script_gks/code_for_ticks.py", line 4, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\chrome.py", line 28, in install
    driver_path = self.download_driver(self.driver)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\manager.py", line 36, in download_driver
    driver_version, is_latest = self.__get_version_to_download(driver)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\manager.py", line 27, in __get_version_to_download
    return self.__get_latest_driver_version(driver), True
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\manager.py", line 21, in __get_latest_driver_version
    return driver.get_latest_release_version()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\driver.py", line 58, in get_latest_release_version
    self._latest_release_url + '_' + chrome_version(self.chrome_type))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\utils.py", line 114, in chrome_version
    .format(cmd)
ValueError: Could not get version for Chrome with this command: reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome\BLBeacon" /v version*
```

Sorry, I am very new to Python, but if somebody could help, I'll be very pleased and thankful.

Answer (score 3):

I solved problem. I don't understand why I've hadn't think of this solution before - all you need to do is to write the path of your chromedriver (only if you have a correct version)
`browser = webdriver.Chrome('path')`

Comment: specifying the path to chromedriver in python script worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

important to know for people searching for the same error and ending here. chrome needs to have started at least once to generate the reg key in windows.

Comment: Thanks, this helped

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are using a selenium web-driver that is not matching your chrome driver version.

you can update your chrome using the following link:
chrome://settings/help

Comment: I"ve dowloaded version of webdriver based on my current version of chrome, so this might not be the case.

Comment: That's what I did as well but I had the same problem you had.
Try to do what I said, worst case it doesn't work...

Comment: The version was correct, but thank you for your help!